# Delay notification issue in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

please help me to solve this issue in SSRS.
all reports were working normally but suddenly this delay notification message appeared i closed the project and reopened it and this notification still appeared 
[Delay Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgP8u.jpg)

Comment: Standard IT fix. Turn your PC off and on again?

Comment: Thanks Mike this solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard IT fix. Turn your PC off and on again